# When to use mlflow.set_tag() vs mlflow.log_params()?

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow

I am confused about the usecase of mlflow.set_tag() vs mlflow.log_params() as both takes key and value pair. Currently, I use mlflow.set_tag() to set tags for data version, code version, etc and mlflow.log_params() to set model training parameters like loss, accuracy, optimizer, etc.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answers:
- Tags can cover dataset s3 path(train/valid), version, # of features, dataset size, shape...
- Params can cover model's backend,booster used,  max/min depth

Answer (score 3):

As teedak8s pointed out in the comments, tags and params are supposed to log different things. Params are **something you want to tune based on the metrics**, whereas tags are some **extra information** that doesn't necessarily associate with the model's performance. See how they use tags and params differently for sklearn, torch, and other packages in the [Automatic Logging](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#automatic-logging). That being said, as I understand it, there's no hard constraint on which to use to log which; they can be used interchangeably without error.